# angular route with module federation

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I am working on a module federation project.

mfe1: ParentApp
mfe2: childApp1
mfe3: childApp2
mfe4: childApp3(parent of ChildApp1)

childApp1 and childApp3 and childApp2 all have routing modules which will navigate to different pages.

My question is how does the parent app know that chdildApp3 changed its routing and ParentApp also needs to change its route?

All the childApp(s) routing path need to be maintained in ParentApp webpack config or there is an alternative way?

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> how does the parent app know that chdildApp3 changed its routing and ParentApp also needs to change its route

One way would be to fire a custom event from your child app & register to that event in your parent app.

In parent `app.component.ts`:

```
@HostListener('window:childRoutechanged',['$event'])
  onChildRouteChange(event)
  {
    
    if(event && event.detail)
    {
      this.location.go(event.detail.microApp+event.detail.route); //Update the url path and also add it to browser's history without actually invoking router
    }
  }
```

In child app's main component file (`app.component.ts`):

```
 this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event=>
        {
          return event instanceof NavigationEnd;
        })
    ).subscribe((event:NavigationEnd)=>
      {
        // create custom event in your micro app. & dispatch it whenever 
          your route changes & you want parent to listen to it
          const routeChangeEv = new CustomEvent('childRoutechanged', {
              detail: {
                microApp: 'child3',
                route:'my/custom/route'
              }
           });
          window.dispatchEvent(routeChangeEv);
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This will have multiple events. microApp: 'child3', might have multiple routes.

Comment: Yes, therefore you subscribe to child app router event in the child's main component i.e. app.component.ts